# How can I write poems in an attractable manner?

Tags: style, poetry

I have written several poems, but only very few won prices. Those poems impressed people very much, so I want you to share your thoughts, what are the key things I have to focus on or I have to keep in my mind, when I write poems.

When I wrote short love poems, five or six lines long, then people love them very much. But sometimes those kinds of poems also become unlikeable, and that's why I shot this question.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding your question. Am I right in guessing that you want some general advice about writing poetry? If you have more specific questions, which would probably be easier to answer, please try to clarify what it is that you're having trouble with.

Comment: @ InkAndPixelClub: Thanks for your Quick Response, what i had asked when you write poems, what are key elements we should keep in mind, in-order to make the poem to impress more and more people and won more and more prizes. so you can point me what you think regarding, writing a good poems

Answer (score 8):

There's a saying I heard in a writing workshop:

- If you don't know what you want to
  say or how you want to say it, write
  a novel.
- If you know what you want to say, but
  not how you want to say it, write a
  short story.
- If you know what you want to say, and
  exactly how you want to say it, write
  a poem.

This means that whatever your subject, you should find precisely the right words to convey your meaning. Remove everything which doesn't belong.

(I might also add that in my humble opinion, I wouldn't write poetry to win a prize, but your mileage may vary, of course.)

Comment: What an awesome statement! I agree that the main difference in poetry is that you have to tell a story in a concise manner with an economy of words. As long as you convey your message in a way that the reader can understand and comprehend, then you have succeeded.

Comment: That was... Shocking! I've never been to a work shop before but it looks like if I did I'd be called (The Non-Know-It-All); I only write novels or rather I start them. Working on that...

Comment: It was said tongue-in-cheek, by a poetry teacher. Take it cum grano salis. :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're asking how to write poetry that people will like, which is not an easy question to answer. Writing is a form of communication, so of course you're going to want other people to read what you write and enjoy it, or at least react to it. But you need to start by writing poetry that **you** like. Trying to guess at what other people are going to like and write based on that is an inexact science at best and it doesn't guarantee that anyone will like your poetry. I could tell you "people like kittens, so you should write poems about kittens" or "people like rhyming poems," but not all people like those things. Even if the majority of people did like rhyming poems about kittens, if it's not something you care about, you'll have a tough time convincing anyone else to care about what you've written.

One of my writing teachers encouraged us to read poetry aloud, both our own and peoms by other writers. I've heard poetry described as music for the speaking voice. The sound and rhythm of the words in a poem is important. If you're not good at hearing how a poem will sound in your head, try reading your work aloud to get a sense of how it sounds. Your readers should be able to get the rhythm of your poem just by reading it, since you're not going to be there to tell them how it should sound. The way a poem sounds is even more important when you're writing free verse, since you don't have a structure to adhere to and it's completely up to you to figure out a meter and words whose sound and meaning will both compliment what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

First off, don't worry about what other people will like when writing a poem. It does not matter, write about what makes you happy. I write poems to let out my feelings and thoughts, things that I think and want other people to hear. I write things that to me are a lot easier written down than said aloud. I don't worry about whether someone will like it or not and I think you shouldn't either.

You can try, but you won't be able to get everyone to like a poem. Everyone has different likes and interests. Don't worry so much about what other people want to hear and what they like and whether they like it or not, what really matters is if you yourself like the poem.

If that poem speaks to you and makes you feel like you just acomplished something, then I suggest you be glad. Keep writing, because it's your thoughts and feelings, your words that you took and wrote down into a beautiful way. Poems are a great way to say what you need to say. To say things that your heart tells you to, but your mind won't let you speak them.

So forget what other people think of your poems. Yes, it's great hearing people say they like or love your poems, it gives you the courage to continue writing. But what really matters is what you think of your poems. Remember that.

Answer (score 1):

Most important of all, when you write, mean it; mean what you write, and how you write it as well.

Learn about all the factors you can that influence the writing, such as assonance and consonance; learn the best way to use punctuation, the way it's usually used and interpret it.

Learn what you use, what those things do, and then use them for your own purpose. Not doing so may result in your poetry being harder to interpret and relate to, and so less attractive.